# How to get a coredump from `abrt`

Tags: gdb, fedora

I'm running Fedora 23, and just recently discovered that `abrt` handles the coredumps from my crashed application, and places all kind of stuff in `/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-date-pid`. Is there a command to fetch a coredump from `abrt`, without manually copying it from the indicated folder? Or could I have `abrt` feed the coredump to gdb, and also load the binary?

I would prefer not to change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`.

I'm thinking somehting along the lines of:

```
$ cc -g -o foo main.c
$ ./foo
segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ abrt-magic d55ba08dd0535a223d4a7...
(gdb) # time to do post mortem debugging...
```

Where of course `abrt-magic` would be replaced with some command

Comment: check logs. `abrt` informs where does it store the dumps and what does it with them.

Comment: As far as I can see `abrt` stores the files `/var/spool/...`, but that directory is only accessible by root which is kind of inconvenient. I'm looking for a more user friendly solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite what you want, but you can use `abrt-cli list` to list the ids and `abrt-cli info -d` on a given id to get the backtrace. You need to configure abrtd to save info for non-package dumps with:

```
sed -i 's/ProcessUnpackaged = no/ProcessUnpackaged = yes/' /etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf
```

---

You can also get an "old-fashioned" core dump in the usual current directory of the process, if the `ulimit -c` value allows it, by setting

```
MakeCompatCore = yes
```

in config file `/etc/abrt/plugins/CCpp.conf`.

Comment: This is pretty much the point where I'm at right now, but it does not give me the coredump without being root. Still, the `abrt-cli info -d` can be really useful otherwise :-). Thanks

Comment: I added how to get old-fashioned core dumps as well.

Comment: Aaaah! I've must've misread it to "CompactCore" and missed that one. That did the trick :-)

Comment: btw, I added your answer on *nix exhange as well. If you want to you can place your answer there and I can mark it as the correct one. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268840/how-to-get-a-coredump-from-abrt